# How to remove space between span elements using inline style only?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I would like to display a single word "WorldWide" in two colors(red and blue).

I've tried using span elements as below.

```
<span style="color:red">World</span><span style="color:blue">Wide</span>
```

but the issue is that the email clients format the html as below so the text ends-up displayed in two words (World Wide instead of WordWide) due the new lines added in the html.

```
<span style="color:red">World
</span>
<span style="color:blue">Wide
</span>
```

So my question is: How can I display a single word in two colors considering that the html clients format/add new lines to span elements? Please note that only inline styling is allowed in email clients so I can't use `<style></style>` tags.

Comment: Alternatively you can use this already red-blue picture of mister Worldwide http://www.iaam.com/artimages/music/Pitbull-rapper.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will go with that one! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can `float` the first element.

```html
<span style="color:red; float: left;">World</span>
<span style="color:blue">Wide</span>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if there are more than 2 words/spans. World Wide was really given only of an example. I didn't realize that the solution may work only for "two" spans and not 3 or more.

Comment: @Books If you have 3 words, float the first two. Or if you have 42 words, float the first 41. Or just float them all, that's fine, too.

Comment: @Books is that why you removed this as the solution? Per your post, my solution solves the problem. Why would you unselect it as a solution because you needed a different solution than what you provided in the post? It's your responsibility to reproduce the problem in the post, and we solve that problem. If your actual problem was different than what you posted, how are we supposed to know that?

Answer (score 0):

The float property specifies whether or not a box (an element) should float.
You may add the `float` in your `span` tag. 
For your code you just need, `float:left` with the first `span` tag.

So it will be

```html
<span style="color:#FF0000; float: left">World</span>
<span style="color:#0D0DFF;">Wide</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know float doesnt work that well with emails. I know spans are inline blocks but adding the code for inline might make it work.

```html
<span style="color:red;display:inline-block;">World</span>
<span style="color:blue;display:inline-block;">Wide</span> and the rest of the words
```

Let me know if this works.